# vtk crashes with opengl needs update using windows 10 and vulkan

Tags: python, opengl, vtk, vulkan

I am using python wrapping to use VTK. I recently upgraded to Windows 10 64 bit, installed my laptop drivers from the relevant manufacturers.I built VTK 7.0 using MSVSC 2010 64 bit with python wrappings. I have switchable graphics card between NVDIA GeForce GT 555M and  Intel HD 3000 Graphics. If I use NVDIA I don't get any vtk object at the renderwin but only the background. If I use Intel Graphics and  run any VTK examples I get the following error:

ERROR: In ......\src\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 545vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow (00000000059F3D40): GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported by your graphics driver but is required for the new OpenGL rendering backend. Please update your OpenGL driver. If you are using Mesa please make sure you have version 10.6.5 or later and make sure your driver in Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2

If I understand right, this happens because Intel HD Graphics installed comes with vulkan, the new generation of OpenGL. But I don't know how can I solve this to work with VTK.Could anyone point out a solution?  Thanks.

Comment: "*If I understand right, this happens because Intel HD Graphics installed comes with vulkan*" Where are you getting that from? Nothing was mentioned about Vulkan in your error message.

Comment: Vulkan is not the "new generation of OpenGL". It's a completely different beast, and don't replace or even superset OpenGL. I guess your Intel GPU doesn't support the required [GL_EXT_GPU_SHADER4](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/gl_listreports.php?listreportsbyextension=GL_EXT_gpu_shader4)  extension. Make sure you have latest drivers. Visit NVidia driver website and update it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks, somehow vulkan  was installed when I upgraded to windows 10, based on Wikipedia for opengl it says; Vulkan, formerly named the "Next Generation OpenGL Initiative" (glNext),[38][39] is a grounds-up redesign effort to unify OpenGL and OpenGL ES into one common API that will not be backwards compatible with existing OpenGL versions.[40][41][42] The initial version of the API was released on 16 February 2016.  So I had the impression that was also an update. I installed the NVidia driver but this didn't change the situation. I'm thinking a clean install to see if it helps

Comment: I found the emails that point out the same problem below: [link] (http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/OpenGL-driver-issue-with-VTK-7-0-td5737190.html#a5740653) I also went back to vtk 6.3 and it worked smoothly.